# Get an outline shape of multiple smaller shapes

Tags: objective-c, drawing, shapes

I have an array of arrays containing points that define polygons. These polygons together form another, final shape. What I want, is to only get the outline points of the final shape in the correct order, so I can draw them on screen.

I have tried removing duplicate points (where two shapes meet, they have exact same points) and sorting them around their centroid and then connecting those, but that gives an approximate outline with many deviations (as of course, connecting the points in a clockwise order is not necessarily correct).

So basically, what I want to do is turn [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezOWZ.jpg) into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsYfI.jpg).

Comment: And what's the language you're using? Do have some code so people can help you out?

Comment: I didn't specify the language, since the problem is the algorithm to achieve this, but it is Objective C. The code so far, as I stated has been a loop going through all the points, and storing them in another array uniquely, then calculating centroid of these points (using the balancing method - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Balancing_method) and then sorting points around it and connecting. But this is not a viable solution, since the order of connecting the points isn't necessarily the same as order around the centroid.